# disconnect the stream but server still emit in webflux

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, server-sent-events

There is a simple api for streaming messages.

```java
    @GetMapping("/channels/{channelCode}")
    public Flux<ServerSentEvent<MessageEvent>> sse(@PathVariable String channelCode) {

        Flux<MessageEvent> messageEventFlux = sinkContainer.getStream(channelCode);
        Flux<MessageEvent> tickFlux = Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(5))
                .map(tick -> new MessageEvent(OffsetDateTime.now(), "HEARTBEAT"));

        return Flux.merge(messageEventFlux, tickFlux)
                .map(event -> ServerSentEvent.builder(event).build());
    }
```

and getStream method is..

```java
    public Flux<M> getStream(String code) {

        return sinksMap
                .computeIfAbsent(code, key -> {
                    MessageSink<M> messageSink = new MessageSink<>();
                    log.debug("open new channel [{}]. channels count: {}", key, sinksMap.size() + 1);
                    return messageSink;
                })
                .toFlux()
                .doOnCancel(() -> {
                    MessageSink<M> messageSink = sinksMap.get(code);
                    if (messageSink.tryClosing()) {
                        sinksMap.remove(code);
                        log.debug("the channel [{}] closed. channels count: {}", code, sinksMap.size());
                    }
                });
    }
```

When I access the api from any browser, I can see messages at the browser.
and if I close that browser tab.
Immediately I can see server logs like below.

```
2022-04-04 10:59:01.143 DEBUG 61355 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] com.example.practicesse.MessageSink      : emit complete for closing result: OK
2022-04-04 10:59:01.143 DEBUG 61355 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] c.e.practicesse.MessageSinkContainer     : the channel [a] closed. channels count: 0.
```

It means doOnCancel() was executed.
That was expected.

But If I call the api by [HTTP Client](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/http-client-in-product-code-editor.html), I could stop receiving by clicking red stop button.
[image]
and then I noticed that there are no logs.
It means doOnCancel() was not executed.
and It still emit 'HEARTBEAT' messages.

Could you explain it? why the method didn't executed. and how to fallback this situation?
You can check out the source code from https://github.com/louishuh/practice-sse

Thank you.

Comment: most likely because the way intellij quits is by calling SIGTERM or something alike on the client, it does not close the connection gracefully. You have other functions, doOnTerminate, doFinally etc etc that you can use.

Comment: @Toerktumlare Thank you for your comment.
I've test what you told me. but they are also not executed.
i've tried doOnTerminate, doAfterTerminate, doFinally.

Comment: maybe I can hold subscription for canceling. but when should I cancel... periodically? is there any solution to know client has gone?